# How to pass data from build script to main program at compile time?

Tags: rust

I have a build script that performs some http requests and constructs a `Vec<(String, String)>` of the responses. I need to pass this data to my main program but I'm not sure what the best way is. My current approach is to write to a source file as a `[(&str, &str); N]` in the build script and include it the main program:

```
// build.rs

let path = env::var("OUT_DIR").expect("no variable called OUT_DIR");
let path = Path::new(&path).join("tags.rs");
let mut output_file = File::create(&path).expect("Failed to create `tags.rs`");
writeln!(output_file, "[")?;
for line in &services_and_tags {
    writeln!(output_file, "({:?}, {:?}),", line.0, line.1)?;
}
writeln!(output_file, "]")?;
```

```
// main.rs

let my_vec = include!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/tags.rs")).to_vec();
```

This works but it feels very clunky. Moreover, since my IDE doesn't know what is being `include!()`ed, I don't get any type hints.

Are there better ways to do this? For my use case it's not important for the file to be human readable.

Comment: A macro? A test generating code?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I was hoping for a way to write my data to a binary file. Writing lines of a source file feels very hacky.

Comment: I don't actually think your solution is that bad. That's kind of how crates like `protobuf` [do it as well](https://docs.rs/protobuf-codegen/latest/protobuf_codegen/#example). They also [use the `OUT_DIR` environment variable](https://docs.rs/protobuf-codegen/3.1.0/src/protobuf_codegen/codegen/mod.rs.html#96).